# Magento + htaccess + mod_rewrite: Forcing trailing slash & Force lower case URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make some changes to my htaccess file for my Magento store to force a trailing slash at the end of all URL's that are not a file AND are not .html (product pages). At the same time, I am trying to force all lower case in URL's as well. Both of these are for SEO reasons, as links to /category, /Category, and /category/ are all viewed as different pages by Google.

Here is the rewrite section of the .htaccess as it stands:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I was shown these two snippets, the first for forcing lower case, the second for trailing slash:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

and...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

However I don't know exactly how or where to insert these into the existing rewrites so everything works as desired.

Comment: The `${lc:}` rewrite map requires you to set it in either server config or vhost config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

and put this in your vhost config or httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
```

Comment: This results in an error page with the following:

    Forbidden

    You don't have permission to access /var/www/html/page/ on this    server.

Comment: Try it with the RewriteBase line I just added? Make sure your directory  and document root are correctly defined in the config.

Comment: That directs any request to /index.php/

Comment: Added the exception for index.php :)

Comment: This works except it is putting trailing slashes on .html pages as well as some images, causing the images to not display.

Comment: Still adds the trailing slash on files.

Comment: That's odd - it shouldn't do that now.

Comment: Almost perfect! I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$ in between the first RewriteCond and RewriteRule to stop it from forcing lower case on images, and then it was perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to make it work for the start page as well?